# static const objects are not retaining values

Tags: c++, function, c++11, int, return

I am making a game similar to that of Minecraft, where all of the various blocks are represented by a single `static const Block <name>;` in the .h file. I initialize them in the .cpp file as `const Block Block::<name> = Block("name", 0, 0);`, and in the constructor I pass in the index of the texture it uses (represented as an unsigned char). In the constructor, it sets the index variable, but when I try to call it later in the program, it returns an entirely different value.

Here are the important parts:

```
Block::Block(std::string name, uint16 id, uint8 tex)
{
    //Check for repeat ids
    if (IdInUse(id))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Block id %u is already in use!", (uint32)id);
        throw std::runtime_error("You cannot reuse block ids!");
    }
    _id = id;
    idMap.insert(std::make_pair(id, *this));
    //Check for repeat names
    if (NameInUse(name))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Block name %s is already in use!", name);
        throw std::runtime_error("You cannot reuse block names!");
    }
    _name = name;
    nameMap.insert(std::make_pair(name, *this));

    _tex = tex;
    fprintf(stdout, "Using texture %u\n", _tex);

    _transparent = false;
}

uint8 Block::GetIndex() const
{
    fprintf(stdout, "Returning texture %u\n", _tex);
    return _tex;
}
```

I am passing 0 into the constructor as `tex`, and printing `_tex` after the assignment prints out 0, so I know that it is getting set properly in the constructor. However, when the program calls `GetIndex()` later on, it always returns 204 for some reason. I do not know why it is doing this, but I think it may have something to do with the fact I declare all of the Blocks to be `static const`. Also, I know that the value of _tex is not getting changed because the object is `const` and the Block is not manipulated in any fashion after being initialized.

If anyone knows what might be causing this, any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

In Block.h, this is the line that declares the blocks, taken from within `class Block`:

```
public:
    static const Block Test;
```

And then in Block.cpp, this is a line towards the top of the file:

```
const Block Block::Test = Block("Test", 1, 0);
```

Here is the entirety of [block.h](http://pastebin.com/g8TLaANH), and [block.cpp](http://pastebin.com/cn6tv4RC).

Comment: Show the actual declarations for your static objects. And the definitions with initializers as well.

Comment: @AndreyT I edited the post to include what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you have a user-defined copy constructor in your class by any chance?

Comment: No, I did not define my own copy constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the objects being placed in`idMap` and `nameMap` by the `Block(string,uint16,uint8)` constructor are copies of the object being constructed - before `_tex` is initialized.

Note that the same problem applies to the `_name` member (at least for the `idMap` collection) and the `_transparent` member.

So when you look up an object from one of those collections, you retrieve an imperfect copy.

You should fully construct the object before adding it to a collection. It might also make more sense to have the maps store a pointer to the object rather than a copy. You should also disable the copy and assignment constructors if you don't intend for these `Block` objects to be copied.

Comment: This completely fixed my problem, thanks. I'm still remotely new to C++ (an therefore to pointers and the like), so I would have never caught this myself. I also changed the maps to hold pointer references, and disabled the copy and assignment constructors. Again, many thanks.

Comment: Although removing the copy constructor now makes the line `const Block Block::Test = Block("Test", 1, 0);` give the error: "Error: function 'Block::Block(const Block&)' cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function." Confusing, considering that I am not using the copy constructor in that line.

Comment: It is also now informing me that `Block(const Block&) = delete;` and `Block& operator=(const Block&) = delete;` are syntactically invalid. I am definitely using C++11, because I am using VS2012 and have been using `nullptr` extensively throughout my code.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the definition of idMap, but it is quite clearly `std::map<uint16, Block>`. This means it contains copies of your Block.
When you push your construct into the map it creates a new Block by calling the copy constructor-> `idMap.insert(std::make_pair(id, *this));`

Notice that this occurs before you set the _tex variable so the new copy has a random _tex value.

You should not pass a pointer to the Block. This will cause a segementation fault the moment Block gets out of scope and is cleaned.

You should really get to know and use boost::flyweight which is the pattern you are trying to use here

Comment: I accepted the other answer, but this one also says the same thing. So thanks for this answer too.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you're actually trying to do, since you don't post sufficient but crucial parts of your code here (the declaration of the `Block` class in particular).

Your statement `static const Block <name>;` seems to imply a template declaration where static member instances need to be defined in the template header, and **not** in a separate .cpp. But if so, I don't believe that your sample code would compile 'as is'.